# PHP - While loop not showing table records

Tags: php

In below code it shows table row value outside while loop but not shows inside while loop. While loop not working; Please let me know whats wrong in it?

```
<?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM cl_banner ORDER BY id;";
      $res = q($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
      { 
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
          { 
             echo $row["title"]; 
             echo "hi";
          } // End While
       } // End If                      
?>
```

Comment: What is `q()` function?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't show inside but outside the loop?

Comment: Please show the code of `q()` function

Comment: Where is the table structure in above code?

Comment: Why the `;` in the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cl_banner ORDER BY id";
                                                 ^^^^
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
              ^^^^^^^^^^ 
        if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
            {   
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
                {   
                    echo $row["title"]; 
                    echo "hi";
                } // End While
            } // End If                     
    ?>
```

Comment: This is the solution. the only improvement is that the OP should update to *MySQLi_*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM cl_banner ORDER BY id";
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
  { 
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
      { 
         echo $row["title"]; 
         echo "hi";
      } // End While
   } // End If                      
?>
```